# digim card not working properly

Tags: asterisk

I have two digium card in same machine. One card is having 4 ports another one card is having single port. I have did the configuration in the system.conf and channel_extensions.conf. 
But after restart the dahdi my 4 port card is working and single port card is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try use dahdi_genconf (not forget archive you current setup)

If you want manual, remmeber you have setup second card starting at port 5(or 9,depend of your first card)

Comment: Why I need to take archive of the current setup? Whether I have to change any settings in the first 4 port card?

Comment: Everytime you do any change you have do backup.That is common practice. Also dahdi_genconf will clear all your file and will try create new.